# dso.dll gives exception as file is not valid compound file

Tags: c#

I'm using `C#.net` for getting document metadata property using `microsoft dso dll` file.
 For many of files(.xls filetype), it gives not a valid compound file format error.
How to handle this error from code ? is there any resolution of this problem ?

[image]

sample code:(Include reference for DSOFile from this location : http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8422)

```
DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties oleobject = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
oleobject.Open(FileName, true, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionOpenReadOnlyIfNoWriteAccess);
SummaryProperties dsoProperties = default(SummaryProperties);
dsoProperties = oleobject.SummaryProperties;     // => this line throws exception
```

Comment: To maximise your chances of getting a good answer this question should be completed with a small snippet of code that reproduces your problem - a note on what file that is causing it, something odd about it and a detailed error exception.

Comment: Did you search for any possible hotfix? Take a look: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/304493

Comment: Tried installing hotfix but its gives setup error in Win7 machine